# Snowflake: In Snowflake SQL how would I select a single field from the users view and put into JSON format?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm finding the snowflake documentation very challenging to follow and derive solutions.

I want to select a list of users from snowflake.  I only need one column (any account login that matches an email address), and I need to put this into JSON format.

I do not want to select any other field except for 'name' (which in our case is an email address).

This should be easy, and maybe it is, but I cannot find any documentation that would lead to a solution.

---

When I do a search on selecting users, I am taken to this page

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-users.html  <== no examples

---

**the command is 'show users;'**

**The problem with this is that:**

1. I cannot select a single field using that command
2. I cannot select where like '%@%' (the simplest match for an account that looks like an email address)
3. I cannot put this into JSON format.

Ideally I would like to do is to select from a view.

With a search, I am led to a 'users view', but I see no examples on that page on how to select from it, and everything I try fails.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/users.html  <== how do I select from this view?

I want to select from a view where the login contains '@' and then put into JSON format.

---

I need JSON output that looks like the following:

```
{
 "users": [

    {"user": '<email_address>'},
    {"user": '<email_address>'},
    {"user": '<email_address>'},
    ...
    ]
}
```

---

Is it even possible to accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitily possible to achieve the exact output as requested.

`RESULT_SCAN` is used to get access of `SHOW USERS` resultset:

```
SHOW USERS;

SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('users', ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('user', "name")))
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) 
WHERE "name" ILIKE '%@%';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try.  I am seeing some SQL functions I have not encountered or used before.  One thing that worries me is that the SQL statement will only work if 'show users;' was executed previously.  I have many users of my system.  What if some user executes a query right after 'show users' and the subsequent SQL statement fails?  It would be ideal if there was a query that did not depend on a previous query, or a way to isolate the two to ensure no other query can interfere with the main SELECT.  thank you.

Comment: @SnowflakeDev RESULT_SCAN can be provided with exact query_id value from [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html) view